# Relationship API name for Task to Opportunity

Tags: formula-field, url

I am trying to create a hyperlink that will take User from the Task back to Opportunity through a custom object (Appointment__c_).

Task -> Appointment__c -> Opportunity (API Name Upgrade_Opportunity)

Formula so far

```
HYPERLINK('/' +   <RelationShipNameHere>,   'Opportunity Name' , '_self' )
```

Relationship from Task -> Appointment is a WhatId

[image]

Relationship from Appointment__c to Opportunity (Upgrade_Opportunity)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kduDAAQ), that has been created 8 years ago, polymorphic fields are still not available in formula fields.

So the answer to your question: it cannot be done with formula fields only. You can try to implement in through trigger on insert / update, so it will retrieve grandparent id to custom field and then you will be able to reference in through URL.